# How to get a domain name username.io from a GitHub page?

Tags: github, dns, domain-name, github-pages

I'm starting a Github page and the domain name I got from GitHub has the format: `username.github.io`. 
How can I get the `username.io` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/should-i-rename-username-github-com-repositories-to-username-github-io) (and [article](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages)) only mention `username.github.io`, that would mean that:

- you need to acquire that domain (`username.io`) from outside GitHub,
- and redirect `username.github.io` to `username.io`

This is what is explained in "[Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages)".

> When you set up a custom domain, the server will automatically create a few redirects for you:
>
> - `username.github.io ⇒ example.com` for user pages
> - `www.example.com ⇒ example.com` for top-level domains
> - `example.com ⇒ www.example.com` if the `www` subdomain is used

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I will only add that https://www.gandi.net seems to have the cheapest prices for .io domains.